# Can't reproduce resisted power circuit on breadboard

Tags: arduino

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fau02x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When i build this circuit on a breadboard, it works find. When I solder a few pieces together to produce it, it kills my Arduino board. I need 9 identical ones, and I made that board, but it failed. Thinking maybe things were too close together for my soldering skills, I made it again but bigger. When that didn't work, I made a single instance of what I need. Still no joy.
I need someone to tell me what the difference is between the breadboard and my board.

This works. Those are 10k ohm resistors, by the way:
[image: Breadboard circuit]
This doesn't work. For some reason, the Arduino programming app won't communicate with my Arduino board. It apparently doesn't like my resisted power leads being plugged into the same types pins on as where the breadboard resisted power went. Even unplugging the power lead from Arduino's 3.3v doesn't help. It doesn't like the blue and white leads. If I untwist them and reset the board, all goes back to normal. I just don't see how they are different from what is on the breadboard.
[image: My board]
Just to show, here is the back side of my board.
[image: Back of board]
I don't do a lot of this, but what I don't understand is that measuring on the breadboard from power to R1 or R2, I get a full needle swing (I don't have digital). Measuring across either resistor doesn't move the needle.
 Then, going to my board, I can measure anywhere from power to R1, across R1, from red lead to either white lead or blue lead, and I get a full needle swing. It's like the resistor isn't there.
This is way too simple to be this difficult.

Comment: draw and post a schematic of what you're trying to do. Use the built-in schematic editor that's on the toolbar when you edit your question.

Comment: Take the multimeter and measure on the disconnected board the resistances between red, blue and white leads.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: I need someone to tell me what the difference is between the breadboard and my board.

Comment: I don't do a lot of this, but what I don't understand is that measuring on the breadboard from power to R1 or R2, I get a full needle swing (I don't have digital). Measuring across either resistor doesn't move the needle.
Then, going to my board, I can measure anywhere from power to R1, across R1, from red lead to either white lead or blue lead, and I get a full needle swing.
How is that possible?

Comment: It is **VERY** unclear what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve. You included a schematic but the photos show an Arduino Mega. *I don't have digital* Neither do I, what does that even mean? Maybe you need to learn a bit more about electronics first?

Comment: Well, to me it seems obvious, but I'll explain:
Forget the Arduino Mega. Look at the breadboard. I have two leads coming from where power should be. Both then have a 10k resistor. Those then plug into pins on the Arduino, but that is irrelevant to the discussion.
Now look at the board I built. Red lead brings in power. that goes down the center of the board to each end where a 10k resistor is attached. One of those goes to a blue lead and one goes to a white lead. 
I don't see a difference between what is on the breadboard and my board.

Comment: If you are causing the Arduino to puke, I suspect either 1) you are in effect shorting its power, or 2) you are inserting a high resistance in it.,  Can you show us the back of the breadboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your PCB.

You see the orange/brown circles with holes in them. These are copper pads where you can solder stuff. You knew that already.

But notice the lighter green areas in between the pads? That's copper with solder-mask on top of it. All the pads in each row are connected! That means your resistors are shorted out.

Maybe you didn't notice the connection, because usually these breadboard PCBs don't have solder mask. Most of them just have copper in between the pads, which is easy to spot.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I rotate the design 90 degrees, it should work. I've only built three of these.

Comment: @JohnUreke Yep. Also you don't need the long wire because the circuit board does that for you (same as a breadboard does). By the way, there are also PCBs which *don't* have these connections, and PCBs with different connections on them